# L.latLngBounds swapping longitude of Northeast and Southwest p

Tags: leaflet

i am trying to adjust map in a certain way. 
logs of general bound:

```
bottomRight: (2) [11.525595058977732, 140.82915421731286]
topLeft: (2) [78.66511070565068, -30.206002032687138]
```

But the LatLng function is changing swapping longitudes:

```
_northEast: LatLng {lat: 78.66511070565068, lng: 140.82915421731286}
_southWest: LatLng {lat: 11.525595058977732, lng: -30.206002032687138}
```

What should i do to prevent this behavior, is there any workaround available?

Comment: What do you try to archive?

bottomRight equals southEast, topLeft equals northWest

Leaflets bound always use the other corners of your rectangle - however you can determine every corner using the coords

Comment: Some more code please!

Comment: i have a huge code base, i can't show here as its strictly confidential. But the idea is pretty much covered in this code. Ever tried L.latLngBounds method? this actually swaps the longitude based on something, its a known issue but i am not getting a solution for this thing no matter what i try.

Comment: Yes I used that function multiple times...
however it works just as defined. When passing in an array, it reads it as [lat, lng]

So i do not understand what goes wrong on your side.
The only "bug" i know there is, that the WGS84 Standard is defined two times, so depending on which draft your data is working you need adjust it. However internally Leaflet works as written in the documentation

Comment: If you can't post your code, post a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.